# Add real-time subtitles during lecture, projected on-screen

Tags: windows, educational, translation

Is there software that could be used to allow someone to type a translation of a lecture as it was being given and to display that translation on a projection screen?

Requirements:

1. The displayed text scrolls at an easy to read rate regardless of the speed of what the translator types
2. The displayed text is large, sharp on a projection screen, and breaks lines well
3. The typing interface can be on a separate screen than the display